# base64 store image in mysql php

Tags: php, android, mysql

I work on android project and my tools in project php and mysql and android.
I have layer want to upload image on it.

Now to store image in database what should i use: normal `varchar` or i use `base64`

Which is better?

And if i use `base64` it must be in android defined as php ?

```
 file_put_contents($ImagePath,base64_decode($ImageData));
```

Comment: what database are you using?

Comment: mysql (phpmyadmin)

Comment: why not use blob?

Comment: no i want to store image data in external folder to avoid increase size of db

Comment: so there are two ways using based64 or varchar to convert image to just url but i dont know whose efficient

Comment: Saving binary data in a relational database is usually problematic, and saving it in Bas64 is making the problem worse. Consider using an object store like Amazon S3 first, this as a last resort.

Comment: is there any source about this ? because i didnt hear about it before

Answer (score 0):

"*no i want to store image data in external folder to avoid increase size of db*"

But **why** do you want to store it in the database then? Or do you want to store a filename or link to its filesystem/cloud storage? Then a VARCHAR should be sufficient. It can be indexed if required.